# Why Call to WebAPI using C# HttpClient returns 401 while it is working using Postman?

Tags: c#, rest, post, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Here is WebAPI EndPoint: https://mysoylplus-apptest.frontierag.co.uk/api/someendpoint

I am sending formData in Postman in key-value pair like below:

```
authenticationData[b64EncryptedSoylSenseInfo] : 'somekey', authenticationData[b64iv] : 'some key'
```

The above thing is working in Postman but when I use `HttpClient` in C# code this is giving me `401 exception`.

What am I doing wrong? I am getting 200 OK using Postman, but I am getting 401 using the below code.

```
string url = "https://mysoylplus-apptest.frontierag.co.uk/api/someendpoint";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                



    using (var httpContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();   

        values.Add("authenticationData[b64EncryptedSoylSenseInfo]", "somekey");
        values.Add("authenticationData[b64iv]", "somekey");


        httpContent.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, httpContent.Content);

        // here is the hash as string
        var result = response.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `HttpRequestMessage` which you're not using, other than to extract the same content out as you put into it? Why not just `client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContnet(values));`? Can you show a screenshot of your form body data from Postman?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SmzxOyD      Please see the screenshot, there is nothing just 2 key value pair. And yes nice point about HttpRequestMessage above.

Comment: It looks like you're posting multipart form data in Postman, not form encoded data as you are in C#